# ¿Como hacer un BETWEEN en un DataTable c#?

Tags: c#, datatable

Hola tengo un datatable con datos que en una columna tiene una fecha, lo que quiero es sacar un promedio con estos datos pero limitados por un between en un datatable, es posible hacer esto?

Por ejemplo tengo 10 rows y yo defino con un datetimepicker el dia de inicio y con otro el dia de fin y de estos 10, 7 estan entre estas fechas que yo definí, entonces es posible saber cuales son? O si es posible filtrarlas?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Has probado alguna cosa? A tu pregunta le falta información para que tenga la calidad sufciente como para no ser cerrada. Añade lo que hayas investigado y probado para que podamos ayudarte, revisa [ask].

Comment: Si tengo algunas ideas de como podría hacerlo, busqué si el datatable podría tener esta propiedad pero no encontré nada, igual trataré de hacerlo de algunas formas que tengo pensado, pero a lo mejor me ahorraria tiempo si datatable tuviera esta propiedad, igual gracias

Comment: Revisate el [`DataTable.Select(...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.8) seguramente es lo que estés buscando, de todas maneras edita la pregunta añade alguna prueba que hayas hecho para que se pueda mantener en la comunidad y algun user te pueda responder a tus dudas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias aplicar `linq` para filtrar los datos

[Crear un objeto DataTable a partir de una consulta (LINQ to DataSet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

Entonces seria algo como

```
var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
               where row.Field<Datetime>("campofecha") > datetimePickerInicio.Value
                  && row.Field<Datetime>("campofecha") <= datetimePickerFin.Value
             select row;
```

Para obtener el `datatable` de respuesta usarias

```
DataTable dtResult = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias es justo lo que estaba buscando, me funcionó a la perfección

Comment: Funciona muy bien pero ya trabajando un poco más con el me di cuenta que si pongo limites por ejemplo del 01/06/19 al 10/06/19 solo me toma los dias 02/06/19 al 10/06/19 y ya cambie los operadores de mayor o menor que, no sabes por que da así? Al parecer los operadores no son porque ya hice varias combinaciones con ellos y no

Comment: Puede ser que tengas que usar el  `>=` o sea `row.Field<Datetime>("campofecha") >= datetimePickerInicio.Value`